Restrict tomcat to share its session with another cluster
I have two tomcat clustered setup in the same network, say first clustered setup has 3 tomcat instances and second clustered setup also has 3 tomcat instances. Now due to all these 6 tomcat instances are in the same network and clustering enabled, all 6 are sharing data to remaining instances but I want my tomcat in the first clustered setup to share its session data with its cluster say in my case I want my tomcat to share its session data with the other 2 instances only. How to achieve this?
In my case each tomcat sharing its session data with other 5 instances
